# Python: Are all dictionary comprehensions just more expressive and compact for loops?

Tags: python

Recently, to describe [dictionary comprehensions in Python](http://www.diveintopython3.net/comprehensions.html), I wrote:

> dictionary comprehension is just a more compact & expressive way of
>   writing the same logic as for loops (performance may differ).

1. Is this a correct characterization of Python's dictionary comprehension?
2. Is it possible to give an objective(-ish) definition of the term expressive used to describe computer code?
3. Does it make sense to use expressive and compact together to describe code? What are some other examples?

Comment: "Compact" and "Expressive" are not formally defined terms, so there can be no correct answer, only opinions.

Comment: @DocBrown How about relatively compact and expressive?

Comment: You missed my point. Maybe you can improve your question by adding *your* definition of "compact" and "expressive".

Comment: @fgnu Are you trying to ask "Are all Python list comprehensions equivalent to for loops?" That would probably be a good question.

Comment: @DocBrown I have added a question to see if we can get a consensus definition of "expressive".

Comment: @Ixrec It was not the question that I intended to ask, because I actually think that dictionary comprehensions _are_ just for loops, but in the interest of asking an objective question, I have framed it as such.

Comment: Can you write a program to transform each valid dictionary comprension into its corresponding equivalent for-loop? If so, you could make the claim that the dictionary comprehension is "syntactic sugar", especially if the Python compiler actually does a similar transformation when compiling the code. I wouldn't say "syntatic sugar" is more 'expressive', just more convenient.

Comment: @Brandin Can I? No. Is it possible? I don't know.

Comment: Not the for-loop itself per se, but it is *the loop's integer counter variable* that is the [accidental property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accident_%28philosophy%29) of walking over a container, if the loop counter's only purpose is to retrieve some item from it, and itself not being used in other ways. Comprehension eliminates that loop counter.

Comment: Though in python, you don't have loop counters.  (Or, at least, you have to do extra work to get at them.)

Comment: @StevenBurnap I can with an `enumerate` right?

Comment: Right, but that is not a common thing to use.

Answer (score 3):

To me, "expressive" means that you can express a large diversity of concepts with it.

In many programming languages, a foreach loop (iterating over a container) is less "expressive" than a for loop. Because you can always trivially rewrite the former in terms of the latter, but not vice versa.

Analogously, I would say that dictionary comprehensions are not *more* expressive than looping constructs, but *less* so.

Comment: For me, "expressive" corresponds to the fact that you can convey ideas is a readable and concise way (as opposed to boiler-plate). Thus, foreach loops and list comprehension are more expressive because they are straightforward to read and usually more concise.

Comment: @Josay Yup, that's definitely different from my definition of "expressive".

Comment: 'Expressive power' has a specific meaning when discussing computer languages, if you use 'expressive' by itself then half your audience will think you mean the non-technical 'effective at conveying meaning' and half will think you mean 'having a greater expressive power'

Comment: might be worth pointing out that less expressive is potentially better IFF the things that cannot be expressed are error prone

Comment: With respect to the "rewrite" test, note that there are situations where a foreach loop cannot be rewritten in terms of an integer-based for-loop. This happens when the container is unordered, i.e. an unordered set, items in hash table, etc. So `foreach` and `for` had their own uniquely applicable situations.

Comment: @rwong It depends on the language but usually you can put something like `hasNext()` as the condition of the `for` loop. There may of course be languages in which this can't be done and neither form subsumes the other.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary comprehension is expressive in the sense that by using one, you are expressing that your intent is to create a dictionary.  You can always do the same thing in a for loop, but doing so does not express that intent.  It is something the reader has to determine by code inspection.  So consider this:

```
cache = {key:lookup(key) for key in keystore}
```

Now compare to a version without a dictionary comprehension:

```
cache = {}
for key in keystore:
    cache[key] = lookup(key)
```

The first version is a bit more compact.  But more importantly, it directly expresses that your intent is to create a dictionary.  In the for loop version, you have to read the code and see that this is what the result is.

The other point to consider is that a dictionary comprehension version is inherently simpler than a for loop version.  A dictionary comprehension cannot fail to produce a dictionary.   There are a number of mistakes that you could potentially make in the for loop version that cannot occur in the dictionary comprehension.

Here's an example of how a comprehension might help avoid a defect:

```
cache = {}
for key in keystore:
    cache[key] = lookup(key)

cache2 = {}
for key in keystore2:
    cache[key] = lookup(key)  # oops
```

We decided to use a second cache, but when copy-pasting, we introduced a defect.  Now look at the dictionary comprehension version:

```
cache = {key:lookup(key) for key in keystore}
cache2 = {key:lookup(key) for key in keystore2}
```

Because `cache` appears twice in the `for` loop version, it is possible for those two instances to become misaligned.  That is impossible with the dictionary comprehension because the target dictionary only appears once.

I know this example seems trivial, but in the real world, with more complex code (for instance, if you have an if/else clause) this problem becomes worse.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the last part?

Comment: sure, I've added an example.

Comment: Your example would be a prime candidate for a function, which makes that problem go away.

Answer (score 1):

IMO expressiveness is a trait of the language/framework/library as a whole - not of a single feature/function in it. Some operations can be better expressed with `for` loops, some with dictionary comprehensions - so I wouldn't say that one is more expressive than the other, but that Python as a whole is more expressive for having both.

Compactness is something that can be used to describe a single feature, but I wouldn't say that dictionary comprehensions are always more compact than `for` loops. For example, I'd argue that

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

is more compact than

```
def foo(x):
    print(x)

{i: foo(i) for i in range(10)}
```

Of course, this is a very obvious abuse of dictionary comprehensions, but there can also be less obvious abuses. The point is that list/dictionary comprehensions targets a more specific use cases than `for` loops, and they can be more compact only in these cases.

If you are looking for the right terminology, I'd say that:

> dictionary comprehension is just a more **functional** way of writing the same logic as for loops (performance may differ).